# NodeJS/Express: implicitly push data from custom middleware into render call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, dust.js

I'm using NodeJS/Express3.

I have some custom middleware which retrieves some data from a database, based on cookie and URL.

I want to have access to this data in the base template (used for all pages).

I can do this explicitly by attaching the data to the `req`, and then using `res.render('template', {foo: req.foo, ...page specific data...});`

I want to make this implicit, so as I add (or remove) custom middleware I don't have to change every render call.

- Is there a way of making data from custom middleware available to render without having to add it to `req` and explicitly pass it through *every* single render request.

I'm using LinkedIn's version of dust.js templates, but I think the question is template engine agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer may lie in `res.locals`.  http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals

Comment: How about app.locals? http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals You'd only have to set them once when the app starts, and they're always available in req.locals.

Comment: @Skelly the data retrieved by this middleware is different for each user and URL.  I think app.locals is for app-level data, not per-request generated data.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't realize your data was per user/session